# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

I know its a kind of duplicate question but none of the suggested answers in the other posts helped me in resolving this Error.so please help me in resolving this error. I know my question has a lot of code to read but i have to post all of my code you guyz can take a look at my whole code.

**My Stacktrace :-**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.vamediabox.vamediaboxapp, PID: 30915
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vamediabox.vamediaboxapp/com.vamediabox.vamediaboxapp.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
      at com.vamediabox.vamediaboxapp.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
      at com.vamediabox.vamediaboxapp.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected end of document
      at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:209)
      at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:122)
      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:250)
      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:174)
      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:100)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
      at com.vamediabox.vamediaboxapp.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**My activity_main.xml :-**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_navigation_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_panel"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**My app_bar_navigation_panel.xml :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.vamediabox.vamediaboxapp.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red_button"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_navigation_panel" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**My content_navigation_panel.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My nav_header_navigation_panel.xml :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="www.vamediabox.com"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My toobar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:background="@drawable/background1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

**My main_drawer.xml :-**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:anroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
        android:title="About Us" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_services"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="Services" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_Portfolio"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_card_travel_black_24dp"
        android:title="Portfolio" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_contact_mail_black_24dp"
        android:title="Contact" />
</group>
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_exit"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
            android:title="Exit" />
    </menu>
</menu>
```

**my home_fragment.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background1"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
tools:context="com.vamediabox.vamediaboxapp.activities.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ly_homeimage">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/socialmedia"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ly_homeimage"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/aluminum"
            android:text="@string/activity_home" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My main_activity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private Bundle bundle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        assert drawer != null;
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        drawer.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        toggle.syncState();
        toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (drawer.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("VAMEDIA BOX");
        setFragment();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void setFragment() {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void showMessageDialog(final boolean exit) {                       

    //Exit Dialog
        final android.app.Dialog popuplayout = new android.app.Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        popuplayout.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        popuplayout.setContentView(R.layout.exitdialog);
        popuplayout.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        Button btnYes = (Button) popuplayout.findViewById(R.id.btnYes);
        Button btnNo = (Button) popuplayout.findViewById(R.id.btnNo);
        TextView tittle = (TextView) popuplayout.findViewById(R.id.txtdialogtitle);
        tittle.setText("");
        TextView msg = (TextView) popuplayout.findViewById(R.id.txtdialogMsg);
        if (!exit)
            msg.setText("Do you want to exit from application?");
        else
            msg.setText("Do you want to exit from application?");
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        popuplayout.show();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(popuplayout.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = (int) (width - (width * 0.20));
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        popuplayout.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

        btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popuplayout.cancel();
                if (!exit) {
                    finish();
                } else {
                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
        btnNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popuplayout.cancel();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            showMessageDialog(true);
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        String title = "";
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home: {
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                title = "VAMEDIA BOX ";
                break;
            }

            case R.id.nav_exit: {
                title = "VAMEDIA BOX";
                showMessageDialog(true);
            }
        }
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        setFragment();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**My HomeFragment.java**

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {      
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public HomeFragment() {

    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected end of document
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:209)

As per official [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml)

```
<menu>
Defines a Menu, which is a container for menu items. A <menu> element must be the root node for the file and can hold one or more <item> and <group> elements.
```

Change your main_drawer.xml like this it will work

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:anroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="Home"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
            android:title="About Us"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_services"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="Services"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Portfolio"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_card_travel_black_24dp"
            android:title="Portfolio"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_contact_mail_black_24dp"
            android:title="Contact"/>

    </group>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_exit"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"

        android:title="Exit"/>


</menu>
```

Comment: thanx mate you saved my day. i was not able to figure where i am going wrong.